# replace two document.write values from two inputs

Tags: javascript, url, document, src

the javascript below replaces this value `http://www.google.co.uk/webhp?hl=en` with `http://link-ads.blogspot.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.uk%2Fwebhp%3Fhl%3Den` on input entry.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showMe(e) {
paramencode = encodeURIComponent(e.value)
document.write('http://link-ads.blogspot.com/?url='+paramencode+'');
}
</script>
<input type="text" id="foo" placeholder="URL here" onchange="showMe(this)" />
```

It works fine but I now need to inclue an `&name=` + value inherited from second input to the end of the document write ie.

```
document.write('http://link-ads.blogspot.com/?url='+paramencode+'&name='+andnameinput+'');
```

where `'+andnameinput+'` will inherit the values from a second `<input>`

**EDITED**
if i insert `http://www.google.co.uk/webhp?hl=en` into the first input

```
<input type="text" id="foo" placeholder="URL here"/>
```

the output from the document.write should be `http://link-ads.blogspot.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.uk%2Fwebhp%3Fhl%3Den`

but it is incomplete as it should have &name= infront with a user input value for that i need a second input

```
<input type="text" id="foo2" placeholder="Name here"/>
```

and say if the value 123456789 was input the output returned from the document.write should be `http://link-ads.blogspot.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.uk%2Fwebhp%3Fhl%3Den&name=123456789`

Comment: As it is, i'm not sure you have to do something, could you explain your problem more precisely or add example

Comment: that's the thing i want to add one, and when something is inserted into it, it will apply the inserted value to `'+andnameinput+'` in the `document.write`

Comment: @Greg yes i will sorry i hadn't already.

Comment: Why are you using `document.write` for this?

Comment: I only know HTML CSS and very little javascript :( unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand well you want something like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showMe(e) {
        paramencode = encodeURIComponent(e.value)
        document.getElementById('urlEncoded').innerHTML = document.getElementById('urlEncoded').innerHTML + 'http://link-ads.blogspot.com/?url='+paramencode;
    }
    function UpdateParam() {
        document.getElementById('urlEncoded').innerHTML = document.getElementById('urlEncoded').innerHTML + '&name='+ document.getElementById('foo2').value;
    }
</script>
<div id="urlEncoded"></div>
<input type="text" id="foo" placeholder="URL here" onchange="showMe(this)" />
<input type="text" id="foo2" placeholder="SecondParam" onchange="UpdateParam()" />
```

Comment: Not sure of the document.write too

Comment: it works but i have a problem . when i input something into the first input it removes the second input bar so its not possible to input anything.

Comment: it's because of your document.write